# Is there a way to test/validate production.rb (or any environment file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a problem in a UAT environment because there was a configuration problem in `config/environments/uat.rb`

Is there a way to test/validate environment files like uat.rb or production.rb to catch errors before deploying?

Loading the files with require in rspec might be a problem because it might affect other tests, not sure about this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying on production, I always run my code in production mode on my development machine using environment flag:

```
rails s --environment=production
```

Comment: a lot of times this isn't reasonable to do as you can't connect to say the production database from your local box.  But agreed this is a possibility.

Comment: For database, I simple change database.yml and point production mode to development database. Once I am through with the testing, I switch back to production database.

Comment: you might have to do for a few things, but anyways I upvoted your answer

Comment: I do not have access to the data base. Also, it does not look like a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

You have to choose what tests you write based on the projected ROI (return on investment) of writing those tests.   Tests aren't free - far from it.  They take time to create and maintain, they junk up your project, etc.  Only write tests that you judge to be useful in the future.

I've had plenty of issues with configuration in the past and the solution has always been KISS - Keep it simple stupid.   Most apps should require very little configuration, thus are hard to mis-configure.

Comment: I do not think answers the question. environment files might be simple ,but you might have a typo and the idea is to catch that error before deploying. In my case, after deploying using passenger, it was hard to figure out the problem was in the environment file.